# Windows Phone Tile Image

Tags: windows-phone-7

What is the point of passing URI of remote image in Windows Phone Tiles? Does it need access to Internet when using URI like http://myurl.com/myimage.png ? Why I cannot make use of local images as background image in tiles and in its updates?

Answer (score 3):

You can use local images. Just create a [StandardTileData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and set the background to be a relative URI as [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: can I schedule tile's background change?

Comment: Yes, with a Scheduled Task Agent, you can let the image update every 30 minutes.

Comment: Any example? Do I use ScheduledTaskAgent or ShellTileSchedule?

Comment: The second link in Claus Jørgensen's answer shows you a way of doing it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I can change the background image to any other from my local resources, but I must use ScheduledTaskAgent rather that ShellTileSchedule?

Comment: Yes, if you want to schedule the tile with a local image, I think the only way will be to use the `ScheduledTaskAgent`.

Comment: See what happens when you post links to answers instead of including answers inline... :)